# Avoid reindxexing of full data while restoring incremental backup in Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am having a database with more than 1 million documents in it. I have to enable 'three character word positions' and create a few new indexes. After performing all this reindexing will be triggered automatically.

Till this moment, it is very straightforward.

Now the tricky part is, I have an incremental backup and while restoring it I want reindexing only for updated data (Data added by incremental backup), but it is getting triggered for complete data (i.e. Data in incremental backup + data present previously).

Is there any way out to reindex only incremental data?

*PS: There are replicas, both active and passive, attached to the databases. We can use them as well for this purpose*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-index and later restore data from backup, you will loose all the re-indexed data. This is what is happening to you.

When you restore, you will be able to restore either full backup or full backup + incremental backups. There is no option to restore only incremental backups.

When you add indexes and after the re-indexing is complete, you need to take full backup or incremental backup (it may contain entire data set if the re-indexing have impacted all the data).

If re-indexing is impacting you, there are multiple options available which you need to choose based on your business case: 
1. Implement tiered-storage - range partition : This helps to segregate data as it comes and assigns the data to specific forest. You may attach and detach forests as needed while adding new indexes. The detached forests data may not be available for application until they are reattached but it will avoid re-indexing to the entire data set when it is not needed. 
2. Implement tiered-storage - sub-databases : This helps to segregate data based on some classification and re-index only the needed sub-databases
3. Database replication - Setup a foreign replica cluster and add indexes in the foreign replica cluster first and enable re-indexer. When the re-indexing is complete, take backup and restore it in the primary cluster whenever you have outage. Add indexes in the primary cluster after the database restore is complete.

Comment: Can you please provide some marklogic documents which says restore will be full+incremental